# Defining Microservice boundaries

Tags: spring-boot, architecture, microservices

I have started learning and building micro service based project, but I always stuck into scoping situation and end up creating a sort of monolith. in my below foo-bar example, please suggest what should be the scoping and how achieve desired output.

**Services or tables**

- Employees
- Department
- Employee-Department-Mapping

**Assumption**

`Employee` or `Department` does not have any cross reference for each other all relationships are maintained in 3rd table `Employee-Department-Mapping` 
Relationship could be `One-To-Many` or `Many-To-Many` based on business to business, in this example it is `One-To-Many` (Department with Employee)

**Requirement**

I want to get total salaries paid department wise. similar to below query, here I am making simple joins on 3 tables. which is only possible if all are in the same database and single micro service.

```sql
Select d.DepartmentName, SUM(e.salary) 
from Employee e, Department d, Employee-Department-Mapping c 
where d.DepartmentName == c.DepartmentName 
AND e.Employee == c.Employee 
Group By c.DepatmentId
```

**constraints**

- employee table has salary information
- employee department relationship is maintained by 3rd table.

I am not looking for exact answer but an approach to solve such problems.
wonder how would you design your micro service if you need aggregated outputs, would you bring all these tables in the single microservice ? I do not want pull millions of records from everymicroservice and do aggregation in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Microservice boundries -if you don't have any other scalability reason- should be defined by the business. And in this particular case -without knowing any other  requirements- I would say you should go for one microservice which manage those 2 entities. Having said that I experienced enough to know that in the real world this solution is not always feasible and possible. Fortunately there are some patterns you can follow to fix the situation you described. For example CQRS could be a solution https://dzone.com/articles/microservices-with-cqrs-and-event-sourcing.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your thinking to microservices here. what I can propose here is

- You will have to do multiple calls to different microservices and return one result you can use [API Gateway](http://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html) pattern. You will have to write an aggregator service to aggregate the output of the two tables via two API services.
- You will have to denormalize the database and have the dept name in your Employees table if you don't like the above option. That's why we use NoSQL in microservices.

Comment: I was thinking aggregation would be a better choice over denormalizing, since this is just a foo-bar example whereas in reality situation could be difficult to manage. well no-sql is slightly better choice over sql db.